# How does ConnectivityManager determine if there's connectivity on the current network

Tags: android

You can check if there's connectivity on Android by using this snippet as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineConnection)

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

But what data does `ConnectivityManager` need to state that the device is currently connected and functional?

As seen on the **AOSP** source code for [ConnectivityManager.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java) file NetworkInfo it´s just a container of the information that `ConnectivityManager` builds. But `ConnectivityManager` gets all the data from a **Interface** called [IConnectivityManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl). I´ve lost the trace here.

```
public NetworkInfo getActiveNetworkInfo() {
    try {
        return mService.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can someone throw a little light here?

Comment: As i know it only checks if you are connected to a network, so its possible for it to return true while not having connection to internet.

Comment: @Nanoc I´m afraid that´s right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectivityManager` calls `getActiveNetworkInfo` of [ConnectivityService](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#L973-L978):

```
@Override
public NetworkInfo getActiveNetworkInfo() {
    enforceAccessPermission();
    final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    NetworkState state = getUnfilteredActiveNetworkState(uid);
    return getFilteredNetworkInfo(state.networkInfo, state.linkProperties, uid);
}
```

- It calls `getUnfilteredActiveNetworkState`[[1]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#L976)
- Then calls `getDefaultNetwork` [[2]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#L890)
- Then get the `NetworkAgentInfo` from the `SparseArray` `mNetworkForRequestId` [[3]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#L3792)

Comment: What parameters does it use to return true in case of positive network connection?

Comment: The value contained in `mState` field of `NetworkInfo` [\[1\]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/core/java/android/net/NetworkInfo.java#L251-L254)

Comment: Yes, but how does it build that value? Does it check that there's no package loss or something like that?

Comment: No, it only returns if the network is connected. It has nothing to do with the internet connection.